# AWK regex split function using multiple delimiters

Tags: regex, awk

I'm trying to use Awk's split function to split input into three fields in order to use the values as field[1], field[2], field[3]. I'm trying to extract the first value: everything (including) the colon, then everything until the first tab (\t) (the hex), then the last field will include everything else.

I've tried multiple regexes and the closest I've come to solving this is:

```
echo -e "ffffffff81000000: 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01\tleaq asdf asdf asdf" \
| awk '{split($0,field,/([:])([ ])|([\t])/); \
print "length of field:" length(field);for (x in field) print field[x]}'
```

But the result doesn't include the colon --and I'm not sure if it's good regex I've written:

```
length of field:3
ffffffff81000000
48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01
leaq asdf asdf asdf
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using the colon as part of a field separator, it will then _disappear_

Comment: I do get the first value ffffffff81000000: including the colon when I take it out, but the other values are then all separated eg 48
8d
25
51
3f
60
01
leaq
asdf
asdf
asdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your `awk` code with some changes:

```
echo -e "ffffffff81000000: 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01\tleaq asdf asdf asdf" | awk -v OFS='\n' '
{
sub(/: */,":\t")
split($0,field,/[\t]/)
print "length of field:" length(field), field[1], field[2],field[3]
}'
length of field:3
ffffffff81000000:
48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01
leaq asdf asdf asdf
```

As you can see:

- added a tab with `sub()`,
- so the separator for `split()` is only `[\t]`,
- and the `OFS` is `\n`.
- And finally only a `print`.

Answer (score 3):

Using `gnu-awk`'s `RS` (for record separator) variable:

```sh
s=$'ffffffff81000000: 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01\tleaq asdf asdf asdf'
awk -v RS='^\\S+|[^\t:]+' '{gsub(/^\s*|\s*$/, "", RT); print RT}' <<< "$s"

ffffffff81000000:
48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01
leaq asdf asdf asdf
```

**Explanation:**

- `RS='^\\S+|[^\t:]+'`: Sets `RS` as 1+ non-whitespace characters at the start OR 1+ of non-tab, non-colon characters
- `gsub(/^\s*|\s*$/, "", RT)` removed whitespace at the start or end from `RT` variable that gets populated because of `RS`
- `print` RT`prints`RT` variable

---

If you want to print length of fields also then use:

```sh
awk -v RS='^\\S+|[^\t:]+' '{gsub(/^\s*|\s*$/, "", RT); print RT} END {print "length of field:", NR}' <<< "$s"

ffffffff81000000:
48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01
leaq asdf asdf asdf
length of field: 3
```

---

If you don't have `gnu-awk` then here is a POSIX awk solution for the same:

```sh
awk '{
   while (match($0, /^[^[:blank:]]+|[^\t:]+/)) {
      print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
      $0 = substr($0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
   }
}' <<< "$s"

ffffffff81000000:
 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01
leaq asdf asdf asdf
```

Comment: I was thinking to add while solution but you added that too, nice solutions, thanks for sharing.

Comment: very nice `match` solution. minor question - I don't think you need the first negation. it could be `/[^[:blank:]]+|[^\t:]+/`

Comment: Thanks. I used `^[^[:blank:]]+` because I wanted 1+ non-whitespaces to be matches only at the start not afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex can be simplified as:

```
split($0,field,/: |\t/)
```

but the result will be the same without containing the colon character
because the delimiter pattern is not included in the splitted result.

If you want to use a complex pattern such as `a whitespace preceded by a colon`
as a delimiter in the split function, you will need to use `PCRE` which is not
supported by `awk`.

Here is an example with `python`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

s = "ffffffff81000000: 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01\tleaq asdf asdf asdf"
print(re.split(r'(?<=:) |\t', s))
```

Output:

```
['ffffffff81000000:', '48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01', 'leaq asdf asdf asdf']
```

You'll see the colon is included in the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub` to replace `:`  with `:\t` and the `\t` with `\n`. You will not find `\n` in a line of awk text unless your programming actions put it there; it is therefor a useful delimiter.  You now can split on `\n` and your code will work as you imagine:

```
echo -e "ffffffff81000000: 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01\tleaq asdf asdf asdf" \
| awk '{sub(/: /,":\t"); gsub(/\t/,"\n"); split($0,field,/\n/)
print "length of field:" length(field)
for (x=1; x<=length(field); x++) print field[x]}'
```

Prints:

```
length of field:3
ffffffff81000000:
48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01
leaq asdf asdf asdf
```

Comment: ++ though I would suggest using `gsub` instead of `sub` as there might be more tab separated fields.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO for a job like this you should use GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match() instead of split():

```
$ echo -e "ffffffff81000000: 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01\tleaq asdf asdf asdf" |
awk '
    match($0,/([^:]+:)\s*([^\t]+)\t(.*)/,field) {
        print "length of field:" length(field);for (x in field) print x, field[x]
    }
'
length of field:12
0start 1
0length 58
3start 40
1start 1
2start 19
3length 19
2length 20
1length 17
0 ffffffff81000000: 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01        leaq asdf asdf asdf
1 ffffffff81000000:
2 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01
3 leaq asdf asdf asdf
```

Note that the resultant array has a lot more information than just the 3 fields that get populated with the strings that match the regexp segments. Just ignore the extra fields if you don't need them:

```
$ echo -e "ffffffff81000000: 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01\tleaq asdf asdf asdf" |
awk '
    match($0,/([^:]+:)\s*([^\t]+)\t(.*)/,field) {
        for (x=1; x<=3; x++) print x, field[x]
    }
'
1 ffffffff81000000:
2 48 8d 25 51 3f 60 01
3 leaq asdf asdf asdf
```